# Why does Sally have a premonition?

Tags: powers, the-nightmare-before-christmas

The Nightmare Before Christmas characters pretty consistently follow a pattern where their traits are related to the kind of monster they are. For example:

- Jack can pull his ribs out to play fetch with his dog because he's a skeleton
- The vampires carry umbrellas during the day because vampires can't handle sunlight
- Santa puts a finger to his nose before flying off because he's, well, Santa
- Sally can tear bits of herself off and sow herself back together because she's an artificial zombie/Frankenstein's Monster

That's where I'm curious why Sally can also have prophetic visions, such as the one where the Christmas tree catches fire. Visions don't seem particularly zombie-like, and they way she reacts and tries to warn Jack seems to indicate she's had visions like this in the past.

Is there some extended universe explanation for why Sally has visions? Alternatively, is there some zombie/automata lore that I'm not aware of that supports the idea they can tell the future?

Comment: Probably just a female intuition trope.  Was Janine really psychic in ghostbusters for example??  https://youtu.be/j-MBS9vAXlY

Comment: One clarification -- [Sally](https://the-nightmare-before-christmas.fandom.com/wiki/Sally) isn't exactly a Zombie / Frankenstein's monster, for all that she resembles one -- she's a Ragdoll, stuffed with dead leaves.  She's very patchwork, but she's not built of living parts, as you can see from her stuffing.  Doesn't help with the question, as far as I know.. but might help block some wrong paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The film's [official novelisation](https://the-nightmare-before-christmas.fandom.com/wiki/Tim_Burton%27s_The_Nightmare_Before_Christmas_(Novel)) indicates that Sally is using a known and time-honoured technique for divining whether someone loves you, namely picking the petals off of a flower or the leaves off of a plant. The plant then seems to turn into something unexpected (a flaming xmas tree) which she attributes to possibly being an omen.

> Now she sat at the town gates, wondering what the future held. Well,
> there was one way to find out. Sally picked a flower and began pulling
> off its petals one by one. "He loves me, he loves me not," she
> whispered. "He loves me. He—" Suddenly the flower in Sally's hand did
> something very strange. It began to twirl around, then changed into a
> miniature Christmas tree! Sally stared at it, not knowing what to
> think. Did this mean that Jack didn't love her? Or was it a an omen
> about his plans for Christmas? She just didn't know. Suddenly the tiny
> tree burst into flames and disappeared, leaving Sally cold, confused,
> and completely in the dark.

If we need to pick a possible culprit, it's possible that Jack himself is causing these odd occurrences by infecting Halloweentown with xmas spirit. That, or Sally is suffering the side-effects of having just recovered from having consumed a double dose of deadly nightshade and jumping out of a window.

Either way there's no indication that Sally has *psychic* powers.